# HttpServletRequestのPOSTパラメータ(日本語)が文字化けする

Tags: java, spring, 文字化け

環境は
tomcat8
Java8
spring4.2
です。

Contoroller側で、POSTリクエストのパラメータを受け取った際、日本語がハングル文字のような状態になります。

viewはファイル自体のエンコードがutf-8で、charsetもutf-8になっています。
server.xmlでも
useBodyEncodingForURI=true
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
となっております。

Springの設定ファイルでもencodingFilterの設定はしています。以下、
WebApplicationInitializerの実装クラスの一部です。

```
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
    characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/");

    servletContext.addListener(new 　　ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));
```

ちなみに文字化けした文字は
「男」→「ç·」
「女」→「å¥³」
です。

ほかに文字コードを設定する場所が思い当たらないので、教えてください。

追記

下記が、コントローラーの呼び出し先メソッドです。

```
@RequestMapping(value="/regist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String regist(@RequestParam("last_name") String lastName,
                     @RequestParam("first_name") String firstName,
                     @RequestParam("mail") String email,
                     @RequestParam("password") String password,
                     @RequestParam("sexal") String sexal,
                     HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

このメソッド内では、DBにユーザー情報を登録する処理を行っております。

文字化けの確認方法は、
1. Eclipseのデバッガを使い、Variablesビューで確認した
2. 登録されたエンティティーをDBサーバーで直接確認した
以上2点でした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

原因がわかりました。
view側で、今後File送信を実装する予定であったため、

```
<form method="POST" action="/regist" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

と記載していました。
もしやと思い、
Controller側で

```
String text = new String(lastName.getByte("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

と書いてみたところ、日本語を取得することができました。

ただ、この場合、MultipartFileをformから送信する場合、
すべてのパラメータに対し、コントローラー側でのエンコード変換が必要になりますが、
もし回避策があるようであれば教えていただけるとうれしいです。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055025/how-to-change-the-character-encoding-for-servlet-3-0-spring-mvc-multipart-upload
にあるような、CommonsMultipartResolverのdefaultEncodingを使う方法はどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

URLのパターンが"/"でなく"/*"であるべきとおもいます。

```
characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/");
```

と言う部分ですが、

```
characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
```

では？

dispatcherTypesに何が指定されているかや、他にFilterがあるのかにもよりますが、
dispatcherTypesもnullにしてEnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST)
isMatchAfterもfalseで良さそうなので、

```
characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

としても良さそうです。

[参考:FilterRegistrationのJavadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/FilterRegistration.html#addMappingForUrlPatterns-java.util.EnumSet-boolean-java.lang.String...-)

Comment: 検証遅くなり申し訳ありません。
これを確認しましたが、文字化けは解消されませんでした。

Comment: そうですか。
Controllerでどの様にPOSTデータを受け取っているか、文字化けはどの様に確認したか(POSTデータを格納した変数の内容をデバッガで見た、ブラウザに表示された文字を見た、データベースに登録された値を見た、など)、教えていただけますか？